# Get StateContext in @OnTransition annotated method

Tags: java, spring, spring-statemachine

In the Spring [Statemachine reference doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/1.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#annotation-support) is this sample code:

```java
@WithStateMachine
static class Bean1 {

    @OnTransition(source = "S1", target = "S2")
    public void fromS1ToS2() {
    }
}
```

Is it possible to access the `StateContext` object from a method annotated with `@OnTransition`? Perhaps I don't understand the correct use of the annotation...I thought it could be used in a similar manner as an `Action`, where I could access data stored in the `ExtendedState`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that I've totally forget to add this specific information on our docs. We can't access `StateContext` but `event headers` and `ExtendedState` are available.

There's a unit test for this in [MethodAnnotationTests](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine/blob/master/spring-statemachine-core/src/test/java/org/springframework/statemachine/annotation/MethodAnnotationTests.java).

Short story is that processor handling method calling detects argument types `ExtendedState` and `Map` if it's annotated with `@EventHeaders`. I've also been thinking to support `StateContext` in a same way via method arguments but haven't yet got that far.

```
@WithStateMachine
public class Bean2 {

  @OnTransition(source = "S1", target = "S2")
  public void method1(@EventHeaders Map<String, Object> headers, ExtendedState extendedState) {
  }

}
```

I'll also get docs sorted out for this, thx for pointing this out!

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I'll look at the tests and source code first next time. I was only interested in `StateContext` as a way to get at `ExtendedState` so this is perfect. Are there plans for additional annotations, maybe something like `@OnStateEnter` and `@OnStateExit`?

Comment: Well yeah having other annotations is not a bad idea at all. Should probably create similar annotations matching functionality from `StateMachineListener` and app context events. I'll create a gh issues for these.

Answer (score 0):

Their documentation says:

> A method annotated with @OnTransition may accept a parameter of type
> ExtendedState, Map if map argument itself is annotated with
> EventHeaders, StateMachine, Message or Exception.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/current/api/org/springframework/statemachine/annotation/OnTransition.html